# NPM audit gives 3 errors I cant resolve

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, npm-install, audit, postcss-loader

I tried installing and adding the v-calendar plugin to my VUE project.
but I am new to vue and don't really understand this errors showing up

`npm audit`

```
# NPM audit report
postcss  <7.0.36
Severity: moderate

Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
No fix available

node_modules/postcss-functions/node_modules/postcss
 postcss-functions  <=3.0.0

Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
 node_modules/postcss-functions

@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat  *
 Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-functions
  node_modules/tailwindcss

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
Some issues need review, and may require choosing a different dependency.
```

As a possible solution, I tried changing my postcss version to 2.0.1, then tried adding postcss-loader as well, but it only solved another error of not finding this plugin.

this is what it shows when I run the project:

[image]

Comment: `severity: moderate` > you can forget about it, especially if it's a DDOS regarding POSTCSS. `No fix available` > everything is pretty clear at this point.

Comment: so I have to just drop the idea of adding the v-calendar plugin to my vue app ? as it was the reason I got this error, but I somehow got errors each times i try adding plugins to my code

Comment: If you run your project, does it work or is this warning blocking the dev compilation?

Comment: everything works perfectly, including tailwindcss styles... only the div where my v-calendar is wont. it only shows the numbers and months without the CSS, which I guess because of the error above